# Movie where something in the water on a farm makes the family go crazy

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

The movie revolved around a small farm where something happened to the water and crazy things started happening.  The plants and animals started growing worms inside of them and the people started going crazy.  I specifically remember the mother sewing through her own hand!

Anyone know what I'm thinking of?

Comment: There was an issue of Fantastic Four where there was an alien thigamajig in the milk that turned people into mutated people. Sorry, that's all I've got.

Comment: This sounds a little like Slither, but I'm sure that's not it (nothing about a mother sewing through her own hand, and Slither is pretty iconic...).  Any specific time period, and more specificity than "crazy things started happening"?

Comment: No these were more like mealworms and it was in the 80s or 90s I think.

Comment: This sounds a little like "The Saliva Tree" by Brian Aldiss. But  your details don't fit.

Comment: 'Don't worry Francis' is what she said whilst sewing her own hand - will never forget it. Was late 80/early 90's movie. Also looking for the name.

Comment: "The Crazies" from George Romero?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sounds like an update to the old Lovecraft story, "[The Colour Out Of Space](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/cs.asp)".  That's essentially the plot, but it sounds like it's been altered considerably.

[*The Curse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curse_(1987_film)), aka *The Farm*, was a 1987 film adaptation.

> A meteorite lands on the property of Nathan Crane (Claude Akins) and local physician Alan Forbes (Cooper Huckabee) is unable to explain why the rock keeps shrinking. He is dissuaded from contacting the authorities by Charlie Davidson (Steve Carlisle), a realtor who does not want the new arrival to discourage the Tennessee Valley Authority (TVA) from establishing a new reservoir in the area. As the rock shrinks away to nothing, a glowing color seeps out and into the ground. Within a few weeks, the farm's crops bloom but are soon discovered to be inedible. Shortly after, the local animals, as well as Nathan's wife, begin to go mad and a previously unknown element is discovered in the property's well. Soon Nathan and his son Cyrus (Malcolm Danare) are driven insane as well and begin terrorizing those who come to the farm, as well as the other children Zack (Wil Wheaton) and Alice (Amy Wheaton). In the film's conclusion, they are saved by TVA representative Carl Willis (John Schneider) and the house collapses into the ground. Compared to previous adaptations of the Lovecraft story this version has been considered a more faithful interpretation.

The worms get mention in [one of the IMDB summaries](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092809/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl):

> .... The fruit and livestock become filled with maggots, cabbage and chickens become filled with green slime, and certain members of the farm family become swollen, slime-drooling mutants ....

The hand-sewing incident also occurs, although the previously linked video depicting it is no longer available.

Comment: Yes!  The title of the movie is apparently The Curse but was based of this story.  Thanks!

Comment: Huh I hadn't noticed this one when looking for Lovecraft based movies, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like it may be [The Crazies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069895/).  I've only seen the 2010 version, which did not include the mother sewing through her hand, nor were there any mention of worms, but those may have been present in the original 1973 version I linked.

Answer (score 4):

*[Impulse](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087464/)*. In this movie an underground storage tank leaks due to an earthquake. A chemical weapon stored in the tank contaminates the local milk supply causing people to lose all impulse control.

The action take place on a dairy farm. Memorable scenes include: 
The underage girl snapping her gum loudly then giving a BJ to Tim Matheson, The kid who gets shot at by the M-16 wielding sheriff, and the guy who breaks a finger by pulling it back till it breaks and proclaiming, "You think you know pain..."

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is *Night of the creeps*, possibly. I saw it when I was younger.

Comment: add more detail to answer

Comment: Please add details of why this answer fits in with the OP's requirements.